# Export function/method from react use effect / hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wavesurfer.js

I have this instance of wavesurfer ni one of my projects. 
This displays various audio files dynamically. 
I'm rendering this on a page where i want play and pause buttons to trigger wave surfer.

I don't quite understand how i can pass these functions?

THey are marked in the code.

THanks in advance!

```
export default function FiddleDisplay({ audioFileUrl }) {
  const waveformRef = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (waveformRef.current) {
      const activeWaveColor = '#f5f5f5';
      const playedWaveColor = '#707070';
      const wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: waveformRef.current,
        barWidth: 5,
        cursorWidth: 2,
        waveColor: activeWaveColor,
        progressColor: playedWaveColor,
        hideScrollbar: true,
        autoCenter: false,
        responsive: true,
        width: 100,
        barHeight: 9,
        height: 350,
        interact: true,
        maxCanvasWidth: 2000,
        fillParent: true
      });
      wavesurfer.load(`${audioFileUrl}`);
      wavesurfer.play(); //USE THIS IN OTHER COMPONENT
      wavesurfer.pause(); //USE THIS IN OTHER COMPONENT
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Waveform ref={waveformRef} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Store a reference to the instance using `useState` and pass it (or bound copies of its methods) down the chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to store the reference to the instance with useState, and attach the relevant bound methods to buttons:

```
export default function FiddleDisplay({
  audioFileUrl,
}) {
  const waveformRef = React.useRef();
  const [waveSurfer, setWaveSurfer] = React.useState();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (waveformRef.current) {
      const activeWaveColor = '#f5f5f5';
      const playedWaveColor = '#707070';
      const wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: waveformRef.current,
        barWidth: 5,
        cursorWidth: 2,
        waveColor: activeWaveColor,
        progressColor: playedWaveColor,
        hideScrollbar: true,
        autoCenter: false,
        responsive: true,
        width: 100,
        barHeight: 9,
        height: 350,
        interact: true,
        maxCanvasWidth: 2000,
        fillParent: true
      });
      wavesurfer.load(`${audioFileUrl}`);
      setWaveSurfer(wavesurfer);
    }
  }, []);

  const play = waveSurfer && waveSurfer.play.bind(waveSurfer);
  const pause = waveSurfer && waveSurfer.pause.bind(waveSurfer);
  return (
    <>
      <Waveform ref={waveformRef} />
      <Button onClick={play}>Play</Button>
      <Button onClick={pause}>Pause</Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

If you want to render the buttons somewhere else, you'll need to pass in a setter from a parent function and pass the bound methods back up.

Comment: thank you so much jared! This is a little advanced for me. I dont really know how to proceed. How do i add this to the onClick's of my buttons. 

I get a message, that the useEffect of the function where this is rendered has a missing dependency setPlayPause. 
As well my browser says setPlayPause is not a function. 
I guess this somehow coincides?

Comment: @SaschaRissling I've updated with a more basic solution. If you want to render the buttons somewhere else you'll have to *create* a setter and pass it in via props to FiddleDisplay, but this should work if you're ok with FiddleDisplay rendering its own buttons.

Comment: Jared thanks a lot. i made it work with your outstanding help. please have a great day

Comment: @SaschaRissling you too!

Comment: jared smith do you think it's possible to look at an other question of mine regarding this? I can't solve it. Thanks in advance. there are not a lot of people looking into wavesurfer react issues 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734627/how-to-stop-wavesurfer-microphone-this-stop-stream-is-not-a-function