# How to stop wavesurfer microphone / `this.stop.stream` is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microphone, getusermedia, wavesurfer.js

I'm running this wavesurfer microphone instance and i'm running into a problem called `this.stop.stream` is not a function whenever i'm trying to stop the microphone after starting it.

This mic does not record anything - it's just visualizing. But in chrome the mic just stays open until reload. Which is not fun for users. And m.

I have found why that happens here => https://wavesurfer-js.org/api/file/src/plugin/microphone.js.html#lineNumber199

all the methods that are called after starting the mic are with "this".

I'm not advanced enough to find out how i could possibly stop that microphone.

Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance

```
  export default function InitialAudioRecording({ handleStop }) {
  const [noAudioYet, setNoAudioYet] = React.useState(true);
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = React.useState(false);
  const [isProcessing, setIsProcessing] = React.useState(false);
  const [waveSurfer, setWaveSurfer] = React.useState();
  const [showWavesurfer, setShowWavesurfer] = React.useState(false);
  const waveformRef = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (waveformRef.current) {
      const themeGradient = getThemeGradient();
      const wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: waveformRef.current,
        barWidth: 5,
        barHeight: 10,
        cursorWidth: 0,
        waveColor: themeGradient,
        hideScrollbar: true,
        autoCenter: false,
        responsive: true,
        interact: false,
        width: 100,
        height: 350,
        maxCanvasWidth: 2000,
        fillParent: true,
        plugins: [MicrophonePlugin.create()]
      });
      wavesurfer.microphone.on('deviceReady', function(stream) {
        console.log('Device ready!', stream);
      });
      wavesurfer.microphone.on('deviceError', function(code) {
        console.warn('Device error: ' + code);
      });
      setWaveSurfer(wavesurfer);
    }
  }, []);

  const stopMicrophone = waveSurfer && waveSurfer.microphone.stopDevice.bind(waveSurfer);

  function startRecording() {
    waveSurfer.microphone.start();
    setShowWavesurfer(true);
    setNoAudioYet(false);
    setIsRecording(true);
  }

  function handleData(recordedBlob) {
    console.log('chunk of real-time data is: ', recordedBlob);
  }

  function stopRecording() {
    waveSurfer.microphone.stop();
    setIsRecording(false);
    setIsProcessing(true);
    setShowWavesurfer(false);
  }

  return (
    <AudioInterfaceWrapper>
      {noAudioYet && (
        <>
          <NoAudioYet systemMessage={'record a fiddle.'} />
        </>
      )}
      {!noAudioYet && (
        <>
          <Mic record={isRecording} onStop={handleStop} onData={handleData} mimeType="audio/webm" />
          {isProcessing && <LoadingLineLong />}
        </>
      )}
      <Waveform showWavesurfer={showWavesurfer} ref={waveformRef} />
      {isRecording && <StopButton onClick={stopRecording} />}
      {!isRecording && !isProcessing && <RecordButton onClick={startRecording} />}
    </AudioInterfaceWrapper>
  );
}
```

Comment: You might have some scope issue here. In the piece of code you're sharing there's no `waveSurfer` property being defined, so unless it's some global, it should'nt be available within stopRecording's scope.

Comment: Oh yeah, there‘s a state being set :-) so it‘s available. Otherwise I wouldn’t be able to start the mic. I‘ll add the state for context. Forgot to share it

Comment: You just need to add a stop button to your returned render and bind that function as a click handler to it. Not clear why it has to be async.

Comment: I have a stop button which on Click Starts the handleStop. 
It‘s async because there‘s more stuff happening. I left that out of here :-)

Comment: added my entire code for better reference.

Comment: I found the issue. I had `setShowWaveSurfer(false)` too early in my chain. OMG. 

Thanks for your help Jordi and Jared. By the way jared. your previous wavesurfer help really made my current project a lot easier. still very glad for that!